# soapUI DataDriven Test Fails On First Run

Tags: web-services, testing, automation, soapui, data-driven-tests

So I have the following request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
     <ns2:GetFacilityRequest xmlns:ns2="http://www.va.gov/VINCIVAFacility">
     <RequestMessageID>123</RequestMessageID>
     <MessageSentDateTime>2012-07-17T13:04:31.238-06:00</MessageSentDateTime>
     <SendingApplication>soapUI</SendingApplication>
     <User>
        <UserID>123</UserID>
     </User>
     <FacilityID>${Facilities#FacilityID}</FacilityID>
     </ns2:GetFacilityRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I run this test, the first test always sends nothing in the FacilityID field and fails. 
How do I fix this?

Comment: whats the error that is returned on the first run?

Comment: I'd suggest adding more tags to your question.  You're more likely to get more eyes on it.

Comment: Steve the only error is a response that the facilityID is required. It is almost like it is reading in a blank record to begin with for whatever reason.

Comment: Where is ${Facilities#FacilityID defined]?

Answer (score 0):

What is here 'Facilities' in ${Facilities#FacilityID}..For different levels you can write in this way
${[scope]propertyName[#xpath-expression]}

where scope can be one of the following literal values:

```
#Project# - references a Project property
#TestSuite# - references a TestSuite property in the containing TestSuite
#TestCase# - references a TestCase property in the containing TestCase
#MockService# - references a MockService property in the containing MockService
#Global# - references a global property (optional)
#System# - references a system property
#Env# - references a environment variable
[TestStep name]# - references a TestStep property within the current TestCase
```